# JQuery popup working in computer browser but not in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have this jQuery file. It is working OK in computer browser, but not in my Nokia Lumia mobile phone browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>JQM popup test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css"/>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/js/"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Tooltip</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</div>
        <div>Other</div>
        <div>Random</div>
        <div>Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you mean not working properly ? as in not showing or ?

Comment: Yes. It is not showing any effect in mobile. It is just an plain text HTML in mobile phones.

I had copied code from jQuery website only. Still not  working.

Comment: how are you viewing this ? through mobile browser ?

Comment: in mobile browser, no css loaded, no JS running. Its just plain HTML page

Comment: I had uploaded file on amazon server. Is it creating problem? I mean may be blocking some css to load?

Comment: ive never used amazon server before, do you have a url we could look at ?

Comment: Its working now! 

Amazon will not allow to load css files, since it was with HTTPS:// protocol.

thanks  thisOneGuy for help!!

Comment: glad you got it working :)

Comment: One more thing, just to share..

Using just **://xyz.com** created a magic and it works well!